# Kivy subclass from Scatter dont have the same behaviour than if a construct the widget

Tags: python, kivy, subclass, scatter

```
class KivyVisor(Scatter):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(KivyVisor, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Image(source='test.jpg'))

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = KivyVisor()
        f.add_widget(s)
        return f
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

this code show an image but i cant rotate o resize it.
but  if i implement just

```
class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        s.add_widget(Image(source='test.jpg'))
        f.add_widget(s)
        return f
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

it works perfectly
Why is that?

Comment: Aren't you adding the image to Scatter on one example, and in the other you are adding image to a FloatLayout?

Comment: I tested both of those examples and they both worked fine for me.  I was able to move, rotate, and resize.  They should both work they are both functionally equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that i had to wait a few seconds before manipulating the image.